# Overlapping lines react recharts

Tags: reactjs, plot, charts, recharts

the react code below allows you to view a series of characters in a graph through the recharts library, as you can see from the code if the values ​​of the graph exceed 90 the color must be green, while as shown in the image below the colors red, yellow and green overlap, how do I fix this?

[image: Image of component]
**React Code:**

```
const formatXAxis = (tickItem) => {
  var date = new Date(+tickItem / 1000);
  return moment(date).format("D MMM HH:mm:ss");
};

const formatBrush = (tickItem) => {
  var date = new Date(+tickItem / 1000);
  return moment(date).format("D MMM");
};

const CustomTooltip = (data) => {
  if (data.payload === null) {
    return (
      <div className="custom-tooltip">
        <p>Nessun dato disponibile</p>
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    // Controllo che il dato esista
    if (typeof data.payload[0] !== "undefined") {
      // Leggo il campo timestamp e formatto la data
      var date = data.payload[0].payload.timestamp;
      date = new Date(+date / 1000);
      return (
        <div className="custom-tooltip">
          <p> Date: {date ? format(date, "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss") : " -- "}</p>
          <p> Value: {data.payload[0].value}</p>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return <p>Nessun dato disponibile</p>;
    }
  }
};

class Charts extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      default: 0,
      calDA: true,
      calA: true,
      valoricharts: [],
      title: "",
      isLoading: false,
    };
    this.loadvalue();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(() => this.setState({ time: this.loadvalue() }), timerefresh);
  }

  async onClickHome() {
    this.props.history.push({
      pathname: "/",
    });
  }
  async onClickDa() {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      calDA: !prevState.calDA,
    }));
  }
  async onClickA() {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      calA: !prevState.calA,
    }));
  }

  async loadvaluefilter(name, nomelivello) {
    var data;
    var dTime;
    var dtemp;
    var newdate = new Date();
    //calcolo tempo
    if (name === "ultimoanno") {
      dTime = Date.now();
      dtemp = new Date(+dTime / 1000);
      newdate = dtemp - 365 * 24 * 3600;
    } else if (name === "ultimi3mesi") {
      dTime = Date.now();
      dtemp = new Date(+dTime / 1000);
      newdate = dtemp - 90 * 24 * 3600;
    } else {
      dTime = Date.now();
      dtemp = new Date(+dTime / 1000);
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
      newdate = dtemp - 30 * 24 * 3600;
    }

    if (nomelivello === "MACHINE") {
      if (name === "ultimoanno") {
        data = await loadvalueplotfilter("UltimoAnno.json");
      } else if (name === "ultimi3mesi") {
        data = await loadvalueplotfilter("Ultimi3Mesi.json");
      } else {
        data = await loadvalueplotfilter("UltimoMese.json");
      }
    } else {
      if (name === "ultimoanno") {
        data = await loadvalueplotfilter("UltimoAnno.json");
      } else if (name === "ultimi3mesi") {
        data = await loadvalueplotfilter("Ultimi3Mesi.json");
      } else {
        data = await loadvalueplotfilter("UltimoMese.json");
      }
    }
    if (data !== undefined && data.length > 0) {
      this.setState({
        valoricharts: [],
        title: "",
      });
      this.setState({
        valoricharts: [...this.state.valoricharts, ...data[0].history],
        title: data[0].name,
      });
    }
  }

  async loadvalue() {
    localStorage.setItem("UpdateDate", moment().format("DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss"));
    var args;
    try {
      this.setState({ isLoading: true });
      args = this.props.location.state.detail;
    } catch (err) {
      args = {
        macchina: localStorage.getItem("macchina1"),
        gruppo: localStorage.getItem("gruppo1"),
        dispositivo: localStorage.getItem("dispositivo1"),
        segnale: localStorage.getItem("segnale1"),
        nomelivello: localStorage.getItem("NomeLivello"),
        nomepadre1: localStorage.getItem("nomepadre1"),
        nomepadre2: localStorage.getItem("nomepadre2"),
        nomepadre3: localStorage.getItem("nomepadre3"),
      };
    }
    var backendvalues = await loadvalueplot();
    this.setState({
      valoricharts: [],
      title: "",
    });

    if (args.macchina !== "") {
      if (args.gruppo !== "") {
        if (args.dispositivo !== "") {
          if (args.segnale !== "") {
            this.setState({
              valoricharts: [
                ...this.state.valoricharts,
                ...backendvalues[0].subitems[args.gruppo].subitems[
                  args.dispositivo
                ].subitems[args.segnale].history,
              ],
              title:
                backendvalues[0].subitems[args.gruppo].subitems[
                  args.dispositivo
                ].subitems[args.segnale].name,
            });
          } else {
            this.setState({
              valoricharts: [
                ...this.state.valoricharts,
                ...backendvalues[0].subitems[args.gruppo].subitems[
                  args.dispositivo
                ].history,
              ],
              title:
                backendvalues[0].subitems[args.gruppo].subitems[
                  args.dispositivo
                ].name,
            });
          }
        } else {
          this.setState({
            valoricharts: [
              ...this.state.valoricharts,
              ...backendvalues[0].subitems[args.gruppo].history,
            ],
            title: backendvalues[0].subitems[args.gruppo].name,
          });
        }
      } else {
        this.setState({
          valoricharts: [
            ...this.state.valoricharts,
            ...backendvalues[0].history,
          ],
          title: backendvalues[0].name,
        });
      }
    }
    this.setState({ isLoading: false });
  }

  getIsLoading() {
    if (this.state.isLoading == false) {
      return (
        <div>
          <Stack sx={{ color: "grey.500" }} spacing={2} direction="row">
            <CircularProgress
              color="warning"
              style={{ marginLeft: 10, marginTop: 5 }}
            />
            In attesa del aggiornamento dati, ultimo aggiornamento eseguito in
            data: {localStorage.getItem("UpdateDate")}
          </Stack>{" "}
        </div>
      );
    } else {
    }
  }

  getWidth() {
    return window.innerWidth <= 1024 ? 400 : 600;
  }

  render() {
    var nomelivello = "";
    var nomepadre1 = "";
    var nomepadre2 = "";
    var nomepadre3 = "";
    try {
      nomelivello = this.props.location.state.detail.nomelivello;
      nomepadre1 = this.props.location.state.detail.nomepadre1;
      nomepadre2 = this.props.location.state.detail.nomepadre2;
      nomepadre3 = this.props.location.state.detail.nomepadre3;
      if (nomelivello === "") {
        nomelivello = this.state.title.toUpperCase();
      }
    } catch (err) {
      nomelivello = localStorage.getItem("NomeLivello");
      nomepadre1 = localStorage.getItem("nomepadre1");
      nomepadre2 = localStorage.getItem("nomepadre2");
      nomepadre3 = localStorage.getItem("nomepadre3");
    }

    return (
      <div className="content">
        <div className="chartPageStyle">
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr id="top" class="tableStyle">
                <td>
                  <h1>{nomelivello}</h1>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="tableStyle">
                <div
                  style={{
                    alignContent: "center",
                    paddingTop: "2%",
                    marginBottom: "5%",
                    marginLeft: "10%",
                  }}
                >
                  <MobileView>
                    <ResponsiveContainer width={200} height="40%">
                      <LineChart
                        width={200}
                        height={400}
                        data={this.state.valoricharts}
                      >
                        <defs>
                          <linearGradient
                            id="colorUv"
                            x1="0%"
                            y1="100%"
                            x2="0%"
                            y2="0%"
                          >
                            <stop offset="0%" stopColor="red" />
                            <stop offset="50%" stopColor="yellow" />
                            <stop offset="90%" stopColor="green" />
                          </linearGradient>
                        </defs>
                        <XAxis
                          dataKey="timestamp"
                          tickFormatter={formatXAxis}
                        />
                        <YAxis
                          dataKey="value"
                          type="number"
                          name="Value"
                          domain={[0, 100]}
                        />
                        <TooltipLineChart content={<CustomTooltip />} />
                        <Legend />
                        <Line
                          dataKey="value"
                          type="number"
                          dot={false}
                          tension="0.2"
                          stroke="url(#colorUv)"
                          strokeWidth={3}
                        />
                        <Brush
                          dataKey="timestamp"
                          height={20}
                          stroke="#8884d8"
                          tickFormatter={formatBrush}
                        />
                      </LineChart>
                    </ResponsiveContainer>
                  </MobileView>
                  <BrowserView>
                    <LineChart
                      width={this.getWidth()}
                      height={400}
                      data={this.state.valoricharts}
                    >
                      <defs>
                        <linearGradient
                          id="colorUv"
                          x1="0%"
                          y1="100%"
                          x2="0%"
                          y2="0%"
                        >
                          <stop offset="0%" stopColor="red" />
                          <stop offset="50%" stopColor="yellow" />
                          <stop offset="90%" stopColor="green" />
                        </linearGradient>
                      </defs>
                      <XAxis dataKey="timestamp" tickFormatter={formatXAxis} />
                      <YAxis
                        dataKey="value"
                        type="number"
                        name="Value"
                        domain={[0, 100]}
                      />
                      <TooltipLineChart content={<CustomTooltip />} />
                      <Legend />
                      <Line
                        dataKey="value"
                        type="number"
                        dot={false}
                        tension="0.2"
                        stroke="url(#colorUv)"
                        strokeWidth={3}
                      />
                      <Brush
                        dataKey="timestamp"
                        height={20}
                        stroke="#8884d8"
                        tickFormatter={formatBrush}
                      />
                    </LineChart>
                  </BrowserView>
                </div>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>

          <div className="buttonStyle">
            <Tooltip title="home">
              <Button
                type="primary"
                shape="circle"
                icon={<HomeOutlined />}
                onClick={() => this.onClickHome()}
              />
            </Tooltip>
            <div className="timeButtonStyle">
              <Button
                style={{ display: "inline", margin: "2px" }}
                onClick={() =>
                  this.loadvaluefilter(
                    "ultimoanno",
                    nomelivello,
                    nomepadre1,
                    nomepadre2,
                    nomepadre3
                  )
                }
              >
                {" "}
                Ultimo anno
              </Button>
              <Button
                style={{ display: "inline", margin: "2px" }}
                onClick={() =>
                  this.loadvaluefilter(
                    "ultimi3mesi",
                    nomelivello,
                    nomepadre1,
                    nomepadre2,
                    nomepadre3
                  )
                }
              >
                Ultimi 3 mesi
              </Button>
              <Button
                style={{ display: "inline", margin: "2px" }}
                onClick={() =>
                  this.loadvaluefilter(
                    "ultimomese",
                    nomelivello,
                    nomepadre1,
                    nomepadre2,
                    nomepadre3
                  )
                }
              >
                Ultimo mese
              </Button>
              <br></br>
              <br></br>
              {this.getIsLoading()}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```